# Reverse proxy for Jenkins in apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, jenkins, httpd.conf

I installed jenkins on my local machine. It's avaliable localhost:8080. I want to configure that I be able to Jenkins from localhost/jenkins

I tryed to put this in my 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: how to output jenkins on localhost/jenkins not on localhost. Localhost must output apache start page